# Content/scripts missing from output after migrating from Apache/MySQL to IIS 7.5 MySQL

Tags: 7

I have recently attempted to deploy a Drupal 7 site to Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 / MySQL 5.6 and I'm getting some very strange results. Many of the Javascript files are not outputting, and some are outputting incorrectly. In addition it seems the content from a number of my page regions is outputting blank. The problem only seems to be affecting the front-end theme which is based on Framework. The back end theme which is working fine is running on Shiny and appears to have no problem. According to Status Report everything is green.

One example of a missing script is that the jQuery Update module is installed and configured to load 1.8, even in the admin interface on IIS. However on the front-end only the core jQuery 1.4.4 is outputting.

I've tried re-importing the SQL multiple times and checking the table statuses and cannot see any difference. Things like URL rewriting are working fine. There are instances of some content outputting, such as node bodies are outputting, but the surrounding header/footers are still completely white. Can't see any errors in the error log and the HTML does not appear to be malformed or truncated.

The server environment specifications and software versions are essentially set in stone as corporate policy, and I'm told that similar environments are in use for other Drupal 7 installations although I do not have access to these.

I'm a bit lost as for where to look where next, anybody else had any similar issues?

Comment: "outputting incorrectly" - that means what, exactly? And are they on new server? Aren't files damaged? Is there any proxy between you and your new server? I'm not sure if this question will ever be answerable, it is not possible for us to debug your site.

Comment: Yeah I realise it's a long shot, but I'm totally out of ideas. There's no proxy, I'm attempting to access the server via localhost on the server itself (via Remote Desktop). By outputting incorrectly I was referring to the core jQuery outputting instead of jQuery Update. Mostly it's just missing scripts and empty regions. That admin interface seems to be fine makes me think it's theme related but I'm really not sure where to start looking. Perhaps I'll try some md5 hashing on all the files and see whether and differences lie there.

Comment: If you think something is theme related, first thing (for me) is to switch to one of core themes and see if it helped.

Comment: Ahh good idea, I'll give it a whirl. Hoping I can replicate the issue in a Windows VM too. Thanks!